# Out of Memory Using Attoparsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

I'm trying to make a simple parser with attoparsec.  The production rules are along the lines of:

```
block:  ?token> [inline]
inline: <?token>foo<?> | anyText
```

So, what I'm trying to get at is, a block starts with the literal ?, followed by a token, followed by a >, followed by a sequence of inlines.

And an inline is either a sequence of the form foo, or just any plain text.

I am having explosive memory use, but I'm not sure how I can factor the parser to avoid it.  The point of the parser I'm writing is to pull out those 'token' things.  Here is my implementation:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Data.Attoparsec.Text as Text
import Data.Text

blockLine :: Parser [Text]
blockLine = do
  block   <- hiddenBlock                       -- the block token
  inlines <- many (hiddenInline <|> inline)    -- followed by inlines, which might have tokens
  return $ block : inlines

inline = manyTill anyChar (hiddenInline <|> (endOfInput >> return Text.empty)) 

hiddenInline = Text.pack <$> do
  char '<'   -- opening "tag"
  char '?'   -- opening "tag" still
  token <- manyTill anyChar (char '>')  -- the token
  manyTill anyChar (string "<?>") -- close the "tag"
  return token

hiddenBlock = Text.pack <$> do
  char '?'
  manyTill anyChar (char '>')
```

This looks, to me, to be a very straightforward translation of the production rules into an LL parser.  I suppose the difficulty is that I'm not sure how to express the production for an inline.  It's supposed to be "arbitrary" text, but the parse should stop as soon as it finds a hiddenInline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your nesting of a call to `manyTill` inside of a use of
`many`.
Since a termination condition of `inline` is `endOfFile`, `manyTill anyChar`
will happily consume all your input and then succeed.
Subsequent uses of `inline` will also succeed, since `manyTill` can run its
first parser *zero* or more times.
So, using `many` on your `inline` parser will just cause `many` to successfully
loop forever while producing an infinite list of empty strings.
This behavior is more obvious with this example

```
 parseOnly (many (manyTill anyChar endOfInput)) $ Text.pack ""
```

The large amount of allocation is probably due to `attoparsec` building up
continuations to manage backtracking.
As a general rule, any parser you feed into `many` should not be able to
trivially succeed (i.e. without consuming any of the input stream).
So, you will need to either rewrite `inline` or otherwise restructure your
parser to avoid this case.